# When saving a CMYK image for web in Illustrator with convert to sRGB ticked, does it automatically convert the image to RGB?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, png, cmyk, rgb

It may sound like a silly qestion but I upload my designs to a website that will later print them onto garments and other stuff. I saw on the website that I should be converting my designs to RGB before uploading them. I haven't had any troubles with it so far but I'm wondering whether it's something I actively need to do if the box for sRGB is ticked.

I've been working in CMYK but then always save them as a PNG which I thought you couldn't do unless they're RGB.

Comment: If you save a png image then yes. However it defeats the purpose of using CMYK mode in the first place.

Comment: PNG images are RGB by default. The format doesn't support CMYK as far as I'm aware - since it's a web image format.

Answer (score 2):

Logic dictates that if you have `convert to sRGB` ticked, things are converted to sRGB. sRGB is RGB, it's merely a specific (and common) RGB color profile.

If the final product is reproduced in RGB, it would be best to work in RGB if possible. Color conversion *can* introduce unwanted colors, although converting from CMYK to RGB is generally less problematic than vice versa.